# How can you compare variance of CDF functions that do not have closed form representation?

Tags: probability, integration, probability-distributions, random-variables, variance

Any help would be appreciated. I am kind of losing my mind over this problem.

Consider

$T(\gamma)=\int_0^\infty\Phi(-\beta(x+\gamma))\Phi'(z+x-\gamma)\, dx$.

Consider, the CDF function defined from T as follow:

$F(y)=\frac{1}{T(\gamma)}\int_0^y\Phi(-\beta(x+\gamma))\Phi'(z+x-\gamma)\,dx$.

How can we show $F$'s variance is increasing in $\gamma$.

Note that $\Phi(x)$ is the CDF of standard normal distribution.

Is this a right kind of argument: (How can I formalize it)

We can rewrite $T$ as follow:

$T=\frac{\beta}{2\pi}\int_{0}^\infty\int_{-y}^0e^{-\frac{1}{2}(x+v-z)^2-\frac{1}{2}(y+v)^2\beta^2}\, dx\, dy$.

When we increase $v$, we decrease means of unconditional bivariate distribution (X,Y). Now if we condition on $-Y<X<0$ and $Y>0$, we cut the distribution along the same place. So the variance should increase?

or this one?
We can say

$T=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-1}^\infty\int_{2}^\infty\beta \gamma^2 e^{-\frac{1}{2}(\gamma x+z)^2-\frac{1}{2}(\gamma x+\gamma y)^2\beta^2}\, dy \, dx$
The inside of the integral is PDF of bivariate normal distribution for $(\gamma X,\gamma(X+Y))$. When $\gamma$ is larger, the variance of $(\gamma X,\gamma(X+Y))$ is larger (I do not even know what does variance of two random variable mean). Hence, if we condition it on $X>-1$ and $Y>2$, the variance should still be larger.

Comment: One can show that $T(\gamma)=Pr(X_1<\alpha(z-2\gamma),X_t>z-\gamma)$, where $(X_1,X_t)$ are bivariate standard normal with correlation $\alpha$ and $\beta=\frac{\alpha}{\sqrt{1-\alpha^2}}$.

Comment: Note that the problem is equivalent to show that $\frac{d^2}{dz^2}\frac{d}{d \gamma}Log(T)>0$.

Comment: Another way to write $T$ is as follow: $T=\gamma^2\beta\int_{-1}^\infty\int_{2}^{\infty}\Phi'(\beta \gamma(x+y))\Phi'(\gamma x+z)\,dy\,dx$. Which means that $\gamma$ is a scaling factor that scales $x$. But it also scales the other variable of integral y.